# What are the pros and cons of consolidating sparsely populated rural counties?

Tags: united-states, administrative-division

Many American states have dozens of small, sparsely populated rural counties.  Some of these counties have fewer than 20k inhabitants.

What are the pros and cons of the state government consolidating some (compact, geographically adjacent) of these counties together?

Comment: As one example, Harding county in New Mexico has ~500 people (about an 1/8th of the population when it was formed in 1921, and 1/1000th of the population of Bernalillo county). Think of all those county jobs that would go away. Whether that is a pro or a con depends on various factors.